# UICollectionView Initial Lag

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2, ios9

I've found several posts already on SO regarding UICollectionView scroll lag however most of them dealt with images, and my situation was a little different and more basic.

I have a uicollectionview that shows the current year, the past year, and the next year (so 36 sections, with x number of days per section). All of this is sorted out on the view's load and is rather fast the way I did it.

The problem, however, is that the initial scroll that takes place in the uicollectionview has a very slight but noticeable lag, and then after that, everything is butter.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
    {

        let day = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarDayCollectionViewCell
```

So you can see here, I have a custom cell and i'm accessing it like above. If i'm in the current month, then the above is called 31 times (or however many days are in that month).

Even if I comment out EVERYTHING in the above code (and just 'day' as is, with no other code below it) it still lags.

Other things I've tried:

1. Wrapping everything I could in dispatch_async
2. Removing almost every bit of code to get a skeleton page running. It still has an initial lag, it's almost as if the sheer # of sections/items are the problem.

So one thing I read was that i'm causing the cell to reload every time and that's creating the initial lag?

```
let day = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarDayCollectionViewCell
```

Someone wrote you need to make this a singleton and stop reinstantiating it, rather access the same one again and again. Is that true? I couldn't see any code that actually did that. I tried something like this:

```
if (day == nil)
        {
            day = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarDayCollectionViewCell
        }
```

and declared day at the top with an initial nil value, but that only caused my app to freeze and become unresponsive.

Could anyone suggest other ideas?
Remember, ideas such as "well you're probably fetching images, or some long-running database call, etc" is not happening - I removed all of my code so the app doesn't even do anything now, and there is still a very minor like 1/4 of a second delay before it's butter.

If I put all my code back, it still does the same thing (initial lag, then everything butter).

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Thanks so much!